# C++ Qt Reflection with Copy and Assignment

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, qobject

As [the `QObject` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator) and many others explain, a `QObject` has an identity and thus hides its copy constructor and assignment operator.

However, I'm not deriving from `QObject` for its dynamic properties feature or the signals/slots feature. I only want **reflection**, or the ability to access `Foo::staticMetaObject`.

```
class Foo : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(Color)
public:
    enum Color { Blue, Red, Pink };
private:
    Color color;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo::Color)
```

I then can't copy `Foo` with:

```
Foo a;
Foo b;
a = b;
```

What's the best way to allow copy and assignment in this case? Do I absolutely need to write a copy constructor and assignment operator? What would they look like? Will reflection still work?

Comment: You mean that doesn't using `QObject`. Because reflection is not the source of the issue here. The issue is that QObject make copy and assignment private (for a good reason).

Comment: @kristianp, good suggestion, I would make that edit *if* @alexisdm didn't provide the exact answer to my exact question. Often times the answer is "don't do what you are asking to do" but in this case, even if that's a reasonable answer, there's also one that does let me do what I want to do: `Q_GADGET`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are only interested in having reflection for

- the class name,
- enums and flags (Q_ENUMS, Q_FLAGS),
- class info ([Q_CLASSINFO](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#Q_CLASSINFO)),

you can use [`Q_GADGET` instead of `Q_OBJECT`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

```
class Foo {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_ENUMS(Color)
public:
    enum Color { Blue, Red, Pink };
private:
    Color color;
};
```

which will declare and define `Foo::staticMetaObject`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't hear from `Q_GADGET` before. So it seems to be a lightweight and static-only version of `Q_OBJECT` which can be very useful in some cases (like this). Sad it's not documented, at least I couldn't find it. This makes it unofficial and thus not guaranteed to work in the future :(

Comment: @leemes It's actually briefly mentioned alongside `Q_OBJECT` on the `QObject` page (I added the link above). But you can say it is pretty well hidden, and I only found about it when searching through the moc source code for something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly implement both a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator in your derived class, but it's likely a sign of bad design. Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {}

private:
    Base(const Base& other) {
        std::cout << "Base copy constructor invoked!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}

    Derived(const Derived& other) {
        std::cout << "Derived copy constructor invoked!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived a;
    Derived b = a;

    return 0;
}
```

This will compile just fine. However, as expected, when you run the resulting program, all that is printed is `Derived copy constructor invoked!`. When the base class declares its copy constructor/copy assignment operator as private, that doesn't prevent derived classes from implementing their own versions. It simply **prevents derived classes from calling the base class versions**.

And therein lies the problem: it's always good practice to make sure you copy all parts of an object, so that you indeed have two distinct copies. Part of your object includes the data owned by the base class, so you should always make sure to invoke the base class's copy constructor/copy assignment operator to ensure that a full copy is made. But that data is by design non-copyable. Thus, it is impossible to copy all parts of the object.

It's up to you if you want to stick with this design. One important thing to ask yourself is, does your derived class really need to be copyable at all? If not, then there's nothing to worry about!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `qt`, but if the copy constructor is not allowed then there should be a reason for it (which is discussed in the link you posted). You can change your design not to have it.

Still if you insist then [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) can be your last resort. I don't recommend it personally, because you have to take care about deep copying, vtable etc. which are not always trivial.